# How do I overwrite a CSS rule?

Tags: css, overwrite

I'm just curious to how I overwrite a CSS with my own ?

Bottomline is, that I have some payment stuff on my website. And the only way I can change the layoyt in the "purchase" section is by changing the CSS. I can't change the HTML it self, or add anything to that. Only change the CSS file.

In the one I'm creating  I have a header that is as follows:

```
#header {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

But the other CSS file, which I can't remove or change, got:

```
#header {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: transparent url("logo-bg.png") repeat-x top;
}
```

And this destroys my header since I don't what that background :)

What's funny though is, that my CSS file is actually last, which I thought would overwrite the other one ? But it doesn't :(

So is there a way to overwrite the background tag so it is not shown ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both selectors are equally [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity); but since your CSS file is included after the rule you're trying to override, just set the `background` property to `none`

```
#header {
    background: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PqdmU/

Answer (score 1):

rulesets don't get overwritten, only individual rules.

```
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
}
```

You don't need the `overflow` and `position` rules either as those will both be inherited from the other ruleset.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your css rule is loaded after the default one, you should be overwriting the rules that have the same (or lower specificity).Hhave a look at the cascading order of css if you want to learn more about that.

As you state your css file is beeing loaded after the default one, that should be safe. The overwriting only applies to style rules you specify, al the rest is inherited from previous rules. In your case you are not overwriting anything, youy are setting a few rules again, but the one you want to change you are ignoring.

To achieve the effect you want, you would have to put the following in your css:

```
#header {
   background-image: none;
}
```

This way you remove the previously set image from the background, keeping all other rules in tact.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background-image to none:

```
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-image: none;
}
```